# Check an iCheck checkbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, icheck

How can I check an iCheck checkbox using JavaScript? Already tried the code:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Documentation](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#methods):

```
$('input').iCheck('check');
```

It'd be good to read the documentation of any plugins you find online, as they usually contain many answers to your questions, thus avoiding the need to ask in forums.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(element).iCheck('check');` where `element` is replaced with the desired element, e.g. `document.getElementById('elementIdHere')`.